# copy thrust ptr from device to host

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have this:

```
mykernel<<<....>>>(....,devCols);

    thrust::device_ptr<float> thrust_dev_ptr_Cols(devCols);
    thrust::inclusive_scan( thrust_dev_ptr_Cols , thrust_dev_ptr_Cols  + numbers ,thrust_dev_ptr_Cols);


    float * raw_ptr = (float*) malloc ( numbers   * sizeof(float) );
    thrust::copy(thrust_dev_ptr_Cols , thrust_dev_ptr_Cols + numbers  ,raw_ptr );

    numberCols = *(raw_ptr + (numbers  -1) );
```

The inclusive scan works fine.
I want to copy the result from the inclusive scan to host and use it to compute numberCols which is just a float variable.

I am trying the above but the numberCols results to zero  (as I said , the inclusive scan works fine).

--------------EDIT----------------

To anyone who might read this post.

This code runs fine too!

It seems the problem was the presenting of results.

(Thanks to  Robert Crovella who "insisted" that this code was ok)

Comment: what is `thrust_dev_ptr_ColConst` ?  Have you read the thrust [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) ?

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Sorry ,a typo error , I corrected. I read it and I saw that it uses vectors.Isn't there a way to copy the contents of device ptr to host?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code you have posted.  I built a simple app around it and it seems to work fine for me.  Results are [here](http://pastebin.com/tbHKWwbT).  Please post a complete code, just as I have, that demonstrates the failure.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Hmm..I don't know.Anyway y, the answer below is correct . ( The thing is that I have the devCols which is allocated on the device and is a parameter for kernel and I am not sure how to present a full working example here).Thank you anyway.

Comment: You post a question suggesting there is a problem with a piece of code.  There is no problem with that code, which I have demonstrated.  You then suggest an answer  is "correct".  I think that will be misleading to future readers, who may infer from your question that there is a problem with your method in thrust.  There is not. You have some other defect in your code, that you don't wish to research.  So I downvoted as an indication to future readers that this is a low-quality question and may be misleading.  "I don't know." suggests a lack of research to me.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Ok, it is good to know.And I will research the problem.Just ,sometimes after coding and coding and running the code and see that you have it "all right" and the result is not ok ,it makes you crazy!

Comment: @George For the same reason I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Ok, you had right.The code was fine.The problem was that I had commented in my code previous declarations which used "size_t" instead of "float" and the printf statement didn't show the correct value for size_t.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> EDIT: See the comments and the EDIT in the original question! This solution is probably not necessary:

Not (necessarily) an answer, but too long for a comment: I don't see a reason why it should not be possible to simply copy the data from the (raw) pointer to the host with `cudaMemcpy`:

```
float* devPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(thrust_dev_ptr_Cols); 
float* hostPtr = (float*)malloc (numbers*sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpy(hostPtr, devPtr, numbers*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

EDIT: BTW, if `devCols` is still known at this point, then you could probably use `devCols` directly instead of the `devPtr` - this is not obvious from the posted code

Comment: Sorry. May I ask how you can be sure that the scan actually works and writes data into the `devCols` pointer? Did you run it in a debugger?

Comment: Don't use `cudaMemcpy` -- use `thrust::copy` to copy from device to host.

Comment: @JaredHoberock Edited the answer accordingly. It was only an attempt to find a workaround for a problem that did not exist with hindsight...

Comment: @Marco13:Sorry about that.. :)